# How do I find a view in a dynamically generated Android layout?

Tags: android

I have a **TableLayout** that I'm populating dynamically.

I'm extending **TableRow** and adding a function called getNextSibling();

(unless this is the wrong way to do this, which I'm happy to alter)...

pseudo code:

```
private TableRow getNextSibling(){
   TableLayout theTable = this.getParent();
   TableRow nextSib = theTable.getChildAt(
                        somehowGetMyIndexOrderInParentTable() + 1);
}
```

I'm not sure how to do this gracefully... I can loop through the children looking for which one of them **== this**  and then see if there's a next one... but I'm guessing there's a more elegant way.

All help welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's dynamically created, you can use `View.setId()` to set the ID value of the view.  Then use `View.findViewById()` to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int) you can assign id's programatically and then use findViewById().

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, since I just was researching on how to create own ids.

You can reserve your own ids and then use those for setId.

```
<resources>
  <item type="id" name="dummy1"/>
  <item type="id" name="dummy2"/>
  <item type="id" name="dummy3"/>
</resources>
```